# How to close refcursor from java

Tags: java, oracle

How to close SYS_REFCURSOR from java after use???

Answer (score 4):

A ref cursor would be closed as any other cursor in java: with [ResultSet.close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29).